# Midline theorem without the axiom of parallels

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Recall that the midline theorem in a Euclidean plane says that the segment between the midpoints of a triangle is parallel to the third side and half as long.

I wonder if we exclude the axiom of parallels, that is, consider a Hilbert plane where the axiom of parallels is not satisfied, is it true that the above mentioned segment is strictly less than a half of the third side? I cannot come up with a proof.

Comment: What would be the definition of a segment?

Comment: The set of all points between P and Q (if we call the midpoints of the first two sides P and Q).

Comment: What does "between" mean, say, in the case of a Hilbert space?

Comment: It is an undefined notion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminary note**

The Statement in the OP cannot be proved without the hyperbolic version of the axiom of parallels. That is, we will assume that in the plane to a straight line through any point not on that straight line at least two parallels can be constructed. (The rest of the Hilbert axioms are assumed to be true.)

---

*First*, let's recall a trivial absolute statement (without proof).

[image]

If $AB=A'B'$ and $AC=A'C'$ and $\angle CAB \ < \ \angle C'A'B'$ then $CB<C'B'$.

*Second*, in hyperbolic geometry the sum of the angles of a triangle is less than $180^{\circ}$

*Third*. Consider a quadrangle.

[image]

Let $AD=BC$ and let $\angle DAB+\angle ABC=180^{\circ}$ then $AB<DC$.

Proof

Taking the the triangle $\triangle DAB$
$$\angle DAB+\angle ABD+\angle ADB\ <\ 180^{\circ}=\angle DAB+\angle ABC=\angle DAB+\angle ABD+\angle DBC.$$

Thus

$$\angle ADB\ <\ \angle DBC.$$

Applying the *First* statement in the case of the triangles $\triangle DAB$ and $\triangle DBC$ we conclude that

$$AB < DC.$$

*Fourth* The OP's theorem

Consider the triangle $\triangle ABC$ below. Let $F$ and $E$ be the midpoints of $BA$ and $CA$. We have to prove that $FE<\frac12 BC$ or, in other words $2FE<BC$.

[image]

Extend the midline $FE$ so that $EF=EH$. Now we have a quadrangle $BFHC$. It is easy to see that $\triangle FAE$ and $\triangle EHC$ are congruent. Thus the two sides of the rectangle $BFHC$ equal: $BF=CH$. Also, the angles $\angle AFE=\angle EHC$. We can say then that $180^{\circ}=\angle BFE+\angle AFE=\angle BFE+\angle EHC=180^{\circ}.$

The assumptions of the *Third* assertion are met. Thus we can tell that

$$2FE<BC.$$